# Detect SFTP Login And Perform A Web Request

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, debian, sftp

I am running a SFTP server on Linux/Debian.
What I want is to detect when a user connects to the Server and then execute a bash script on the server in which I perform a web request.
In this web request i want to pass through the username and the ip address of the new connected user.

I have already tried to write my script to the /etc/profile file but this doesn't work because this file only gets executed when I log on to the shell and not on sftp connections.

Is there a way I can achieve my goal?

Comment: You would need to check the system logs periodically for successful SSH logins. The same script would also make the web request. This can be achieved easily with Python.